# How to introduce delay within a RxJava group processed parallely?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

My use case is to group a stream, start processing some of the groups parallely, and within each group, delay processing of each item by a constant interval. I can't seem to get the delay within the group right because instead of being emitted periodically, they are emitted almost instantaneously. Following is my test code using RxJava 2.0.5:

```
@Slf4j
public class GroupsAndDelays {
    Function<Integer, Flowable<Integer>> remoteClient;
    int groupMemberDelaySeconds;
    int remoteCallTimeoutSeconds;
    int maxRetryCount;
    int retryDelaySeconds;
    Map<Long, List<Integer>> threadMap;
    Map<Long, List<Integer>> resultThreadMap;

    public ParallelFlowable<Integer> doStuff(Flowable<Integer> src,
                                             Function<Integer, Integer> groupByFn,
                                             Function<Integer, Flowable<Integer>> responseMapper) {
        return src
                .groupBy(groupByFn)
                .parallel(5).runOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .map(g -> g.distinct().toList())
                .flatMap(i -> i.toFlowable())
                .flatMap(i -> {
                    log.debug("Processing group: {}.", i);
                    return Flowable.fromIterable(i)
                            .delay(groupMemberDelaySeconds, SECONDS);
                })
                .flatMap(i -> {
                    log.debug("Processing: {}.", i);
                    putInThreadMap(threadMap, i);
                    return remoteCall(i * 2, responseMapper);
                });
    }

    private Flowable<Integer> remoteCall(int i, Function<Integer, Flowable<Integer>> responseMapper) throws
            Exception {
        return remoteClient.apply(i)
                .timeout(remoteCallTimeoutSeconds, SECONDS)
                .retryWhen(t -> t.zipWith(Flowable.range(1, maxRetryCount), (ex, retryCount) -> retryCount)
                        .flatMap(retryCount -> Flowable.timer(retryCount * retryDelaySeconds, SECONDS)))
                .flatMap(result -> {
                    log.debug("Processing result: {}.", result);
                    putInThreadMap(resultThreadMap, result);
                    return responseMapper.apply(result);
                })
                .onErrorReturnItem(-1);
    }

    private void putInThreadMap(Map<Long, List<Integer>> map, int i) {
        map.merge(Thread.currentThread().getId(), singletonList(i), this::merge);
    }

    private List<Integer> merge(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
        return Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Here's a Spock test:

```
class GroupsAndDelaysSpec extends Specification {
    final int groupMemberDelaySeconds = 3
    final int remoteCallTimeoutSeconds = 3
    final int maxRetryCount = 2
    final int retryDelaySeconds = 2
    Function<Integer, Flowable<Integer>> remoteClient
    Function<Integer, Integer> groupByFn
    Function<Integer, Flowable<Integer>> responseMapper

    GroupsAndDelays groupsAndDelays

    final Flowable<Integer> src = Flowable.fromArray(
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
            11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
            21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
            31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
            41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45
    )

    def setup() {
        remoteClient = Mock(Function)

        groupsAndDelays = new GroupsAndDelays()
        groupsAndDelays.groupMemberDelaySeconds = groupMemberDelaySeconds
        groupsAndDelays.remoteCallTimeoutSeconds = remoteCallTimeoutSeconds
        groupsAndDelays.maxRetryCount = maxRetryCount
        groupsAndDelays.retryDelaySeconds = retryDelaySeconds
        groupsAndDelays.remoteClient = remoteClient
        groupsAndDelays.threadMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, List<Integer>>()
        groupsAndDelays.resultThreadMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, List<Integer>>()

        groupByFn = Mock(Function)
        groupByFn.apply(_) >> { args -> args[0] % 10 }

        responseMapper = Mock(Function)
        responseMapper.apply(_) >> { args -> args[0] }
    }

    def cleanup() {
        println("Thread map: ${groupsAndDelays.threadMap}")
        println("Result thread map: ${groupsAndDelays.resultThreadMap}")

        assert groupsAndDelays.threadMap.size() == 5
        assert groupsAndDelays.threadMap.findAll { k, v -> v.size() == 5 }.size() == 5
    }

    def "each group executes on a separate thread"() {
        setup:
        remoteClient.apply(_) >> { args -> Flowable.just(args[0]) }

        when:
        groupsAndDelays.doStuff(src, groupByFn, responseMapper)
                .sequential()
                .toList()
                .blockingGet()

        then:
        true
    }
}
```

Sample run:

```
2017-02-04 00:49:19.430 [RxNewThreadScheduler-3] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$1 - Processing group: [3, 13, 23, 33, 43].
2017-02-04 00:49:19.430 [RxNewThreadScheduler-1] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$1 - Processing group: [1, 11, 21, 31, 41].
2017-02-04 00:49:19.430 [RxNewThreadScheduler-5] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$1 - Processing group: [5, 15, 25, 35, 45].
2017-02-04 00:49:19.430 [RxNewThreadScheduler-2] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$1 - Processing group: [2, 12, 22, 32, 42].
2017-02-04 00:49:19.430 [RxNewThreadScheduler-4] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$1 - Processing group: [4, 14, 24, 34, 44].
2017-02-04 00:49:22.443 [RxComputationThreadPool-2] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 2.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.443 [RxComputationThreadPool-1] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 1.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.443 [RxComputationThreadPool-5] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 5.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.443 [RxComputationThreadPool-4] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 4.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.443 [RxComputationThreadPool-3] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 3.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.456 [RxComputationThreadPool-5] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 10.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.456 [RxComputationThreadPool-1] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 2.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.456 [RxComputationThreadPool-4] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 8.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.456 [RxComputationThreadPool-3] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 6.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.456 [RxComputationThreadPool-2] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 4.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.459 [RxComputationThreadPool-3] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 13.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.459 [RxComputationThreadPool-4] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 14.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.459 [RxComputationThreadPool-1] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 11.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.459 [RxComputationThreadPool-5] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 15.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.459 [RxComputationThreadPool-2] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 12.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.466 [RxComputationThreadPool-3] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 26.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.466 [RxComputationThreadPool-5] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 30.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.466 [RxComputationThreadPool-2] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 24.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.466 [RxComputationThreadPool-1] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 22.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.466 [RxComputationThreadPool-4] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 28.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.466 [RxComputationThreadPool-3] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 23.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.467 [RxComputationThreadPool-5] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 25.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.467 [RxComputationThreadPool-2] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 22.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.467 [RxComputationThreadPool-1] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 21.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.467 [RxComputationThreadPool-4] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 24.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.467 [RxComputationThreadPool-3] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 46.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.467 [RxComputationThreadPool-5] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 50.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.467 [RxComputationThreadPool-2] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 44.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.468 [RxComputationThreadPool-1] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 42.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.468 [RxComputationThreadPool-4] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 48.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.468 [RxComputationThreadPool-3] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 33.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.468 [RxComputationThreadPool-5] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 35.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.468 [RxComputationThreadPool-2] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 32.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.468 [RxComputationThreadPool-1] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 31.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.468 [RxComputationThreadPool-4] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 34.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.469 [RxComputationThreadPool-3] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 66.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.469 [RxComputationThreadPool-1] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 62.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.469 [RxComputationThreadPool-4] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 68.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.469 [RxComputationThreadPool-2] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 64.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.469 [RxComputationThreadPool-5] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 70.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.470 [RxComputationThreadPool-3] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 43.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.470 [RxComputationThreadPool-4] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 44.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.470 [RxComputationThreadPool-1] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 41.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.470 [RxComputationThreadPool-2] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 42.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.470 [RxComputationThreadPool-5] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$6 - Processing: 45.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.470 [RxComputationThreadPool-3] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 86.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.470 [RxComputationThreadPool-4] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 88.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.470 [RxComputationThreadPool-1] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 82.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.470 [RxComputationThreadPool-2] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 84.
2017-02-04 00:49:22.470 [RxComputationThreadPool-5] [DEBUG] n.a.j.r.GroupsAndDelays.lambda$null$5 - Processing result: 90.
Thread map: [20:[3, 13, 23, 33, 43], 21:[2, 12, 22, 32, 42], 22:[5, 15, 25, 35, 45], 23:[4, 14, 24, 34, 44], 24:[1, 11, 21, 31, 41]]
Result thread map: [20:[6, 26, 46, 66, 86], 21:[4, 24, 44, 64, 84], 22:[10, 30, 50, 70, 90], 23:[8, 28, 48, 68, 88], 24:[2, 22, 42, 62, 82]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Edit**:

Bonus points if you can also show how to do this in [project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/).

**Edit 2**:
The solution using project Reactor is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082334/reactive-parallelization-doesnt-work/42094037).

Answer (score 3):

The RxJava 2 Extensions library contains the `spanout` [operator](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersspanout).

Replace `delay()` with

```
compose(FlowableTransformers.spanout(
    groupMemberDelaySeconds, groupMemberDelaySeconds, SECONDS))
```

Comment: Why do you say that David?  I'm also trying out project Reactor (see edit).

Comment: Who do you think did most of RxJava 2, and significant part Reactor 3 for the matter of fact?

Comment: Trust me, I understand the sentiment, been there, done that. I'm not undermining your contribution to those projects. But I'd like to see more people taking interest in maintaining the code, not one person becoming a bottleneck. Didn't RxJava1 development slow down after Ben Christensen left?

Comment: There was no development bottleneck on RxJava, only managerial before I took the lead last June.

Comment: You are looking for Flux#delayElements operator in reactor I think ? (3.0.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, used to be call just delay in 3.0.4 <)

Comment: @smaldini I'm having a lot of trouble getting it working, Does project reactor have a Gitter channel for discussions?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that in you want to insert delays between emissions from iterable which is returned in this flatMap:

```
.flatMap(i -> {
   log.debug("Processing group: {}.", i);
       return Flowable.fromIterable(i)
           .delay(groupMemberDelaySeconds, SECONDS);
})
```

In that case, you misinterpreted `delay` operator. It simply shifts the emissions by the specified time. To insert a delay between each emission, you can zip it with `interval` observable

```
.flatMap(i -> {
   log.debug("Processing group: {}.", i);
       return Flowable.fromIterable(i)
           .zipWith(Flowable.interval(groupMemberDelaySeconds, SECONDS), (item, time) -> item)
})
```

***However***, you need to understand that this approach is only valid when you can be certain that your observable is ***always*** producing more frequently than the specified interval, otherwise you can end up with buffering up emissions from interval and that would mean instantaneous emitting from desired observable as soon as they come in for the next several items, depending on the number of events that buffered up from interval observable. Of course, there are ways to work around this, but this one is much simpler and when you are working with Iterable, you can be sure (*within reason*) that it won't happen.

Comment: You're probably right, I modified my comment. I've since migrated to using project Reactor instead of RxJava2 and couldn't place your comment with the code. I'll respond after having tried this.
I've added an edit to my question asking how to do this in project Reactor.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below. Key is to use `zipWith` combined with `interval` and that ensures the time specific emission of all items.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<Integer> o1 = Observable.range(1, 3);
    System.out.println("Without delay");
    o1.subscribe(v -> System.out.println(v));

    System.out.println("With delay");
    o1.zipWith(Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (a, b)->a ).subscribe(a->System.out.println(a));
    Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).toBlocking().subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Where is the groupBy and parallel processing of groups thereof?

Comment: Well, this is not a whole solution, but an example implementation to introduce the delay you needed. Based on this, the complete solution for the problem should be tailored.